# Building concept map for a programming language using wikipedia and/or stackexchange queries

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, data-science, wikipedia, stackexchange-api

I've been fiddling around with wiki api and stack exchange queries and thought it would be interesting to create a hierarchy map or a weighted concept (undirected) map for a programming language. Thought it would create a useful generic graph layer that could possibly help people to learn a programming language faster. I haven't really thought of the details of this project yet but I need guidance as to where to start. Can anyone direct me to a good resource or an idea where I can build off of?

Comment: That's an interesting question, but I think it's more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com since it's about model building instead of a specific programming question.

Comment: I second @RobertDodier's comment. This should probably be migrated to stats.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs with [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) SO forum.